# Are apacite and newtxmath incompatible?

Tags: newtxmath, apacite

With `newtxmath 2016/10/15 v1.51` and `apacite 2013/07/21 v6.03`, if `newtxmath` is loaded before `apacite`, we get errors about `\BIP`, `\BIn` etc already defined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}
Anything!
\end{document}

! LaTeX Error: Command \BIP already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

If `apacite` is loaded *before* `newtxmath`, no error is thrown. The references *look* fine i.e. various APAcite strings e.g. `\BIP` is still "in press".

Should this be considered a bug? Would there be any side effects to either packages if `apacite` is loaded before `newtxmath`?

Comment: Looks like it: `newtxmath` defines a whole load of `\BI<letter>` commands.

Comment: I filed an issue report to M. Sharpe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `newtxmath` package defines the commands `\BIA` to `\BIZ` and `\BIa` to `\BIz` for “bold italic letter”.

<sub>In my opinion it shouldn't: users can and should use `bm` instead.</sub>

However, there's apparently no problem in doing like you ended up with.

Indeed, `apacite.sty` defines `\BIP`, then `newtxmath` overrides this definition, but `apacite` also loads an `.apc` file at begin document and `english.apc` has

```
\renewcommand{\BIP}{in press}%            % ``in press''
\renewcommand{\BIn}{In}%                  % for ``In '' editor...
```

so the two macros that are overwritten by `newtxmath` get overwritten again.

The problem could show up if an unsupported language is used, that is not among Dutch, Finnish, German, Spanish, English, French, Greek, Norwegian and Swedish. In those cases the user should supply appropriate `\renewcommand` for those two macros anyway.

## Update

As of version 1.513 of `newtxmath`, the `\BIx` (`x` representing any letter) are not defined by default any more and are only available if the `useBImacros` option is passed at package loading.

> [Changes in version 1.513](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/newtx/README?view=markup&sortby=date&pathrev=42480)
>   Changed availability of `\BIx` macros to work around conflicts with other packages. They may now be enabled with the option `useBImacros`, otherwise thay are disabled.